# 1 request send many times with stepping thread group

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, jmeter-plugins, threadgroup

I met a problem when using Stepping Thread Group in jmeter that a request is sent many times.

For example:
I have 1 csv that contains 100 users and passwords for login system.
I want to test with 10 concurrent users using Stepping Thread Group in jmeter.
I setup the params as piture.
[Stepping Thread Group setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGz6W.png)

And observe result that login request sent many times and the number of loged-in users is more than 10.

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks

Updated question:

Besides, I want to execute scenario like this.
1. login
2. do stuff 01
3. do stuff 02
4. logout

Constrain 01 - During a user execute step 3, all others must wait and donot execute step 2 until user finishes step 3.

Constrain 02 - When step 3 finished, only 1 user execute step 2, others wait again.

is there any controller help this scenario? 
I can setup a while controller for solving Constrain 01. But for contrain 02, I donot found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute request(s) only 10 times - just put them under [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and configure it like:

[image: JMeter Throughput Controller]

Also be aware that as of now Stepping Thread Group is **deprecated** and users are encouraged to go for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) instead. See [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter Part 4 - Stepping Thread Group and Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread) to learn more about things in common and what is different.

Comment: thank you for your reply. It helps me alot.
Could you help me for the updated scenario in question?